# how to change the tag?

Tags: json, xml

i used fast-xml-parser to Transform JSON to XML.
But how to change the number tag to 'ul' tag?

```
jsonArr.push({
    loc: '123',
    lastmod
})
var parser = new Parser({
     format: true,
     indentBy: "    "
    });
    var xml = parser.parse(jsonArr);

-------------------------------------------


<0>
    <loc>123</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-04-29</lastmod>
</0>
<1>
    <loc>123</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-04-28</lastmod>
</1>
...
```

Comment: If you're using a tool that purports to generate XML, but generates output that is patently NOT XML, then I would put that tool straight in the trash and find a better one. Having said that, no JSON-to-XML tool is ever going to generate precisely the XML that you want, and you probably need to be prepared to transform it (e.g. using XSLT) after conversion. But you can only use XSLT if the XML is actually well-formed to start with.